# How to calculate probabilities using log

Tags: probability, logarithms

I'm messing around with password cracking theory and am attempting to calculate the probability of a password being cracked while utilising a random dictionary attack.
Instead of going down a list of passwords, the random cracking attack selects entries from the list at random.
So if a password is 1 of 1000 words, and every day I was to attempt one of these words at random, how many days on average would it take me to guess the password?  I'm not sure if I'm overthinking this.
Could anybody help me out with the algorithm used?  I'm sure it contains the log function, but I'm beat aside from that.

Comment: It takes 500 days, on average.  No need for log.

Comment: Do you throw out the words that have failed?  If you don't, then (if $E$ is the answer) we have $E=\frac 1{1000}\times 1 +\frac {999}{1000}\times (E+1)\implies E=1000$.

Comment: Put differently, that's a geometric distribution with parameter $1/1000$. If I may, *why* were you expecting a logarithm to show up?

Comment: Thanks so much guys, I knew it must have been a known mathematical function, I just didn't know where to start Googling!

Comment: Just to repeat:  it makes a big difference if your algorithm throws out the failures or if, alternatively, it is allowed to repeat them.  If you throw them out then the answer is $\sum_{n=1}^{1000} \frac 1{1000}\times n=\frac {1001}2$.

Comment: This is a geometric distribution. The mean is $1/p$, where $p$ is the probability of success. In this case we have that $p=1/1000$, hence the mean (aka the expected value of the random variable) is $1000$.